Is Sabbath "Rooted in Creation" in Exodus 20:11?
This is a question particularly for those who believe, based on Biblical data in the New Testament, that the Sabbath is no longer binding for New Covenant Christians since Jesus has fulfilled the Law and has become our rest. Particularly for those of you who hold this theological view (please neglect to answer if you don't hold this view, as the question will not apply to you) how do you interpret Exodus 20:11 in particular, and reconcile it with your theology? I will explain what I mean, and then conclude with my concrete question at the bottom.
After the command to observe the Sabbath, Exodus 20:11 in the ESV says: "For in six days the Lord made heaven and earth, the sea, and all that is in them, and rested on the seventh day. Therefore the Lord blessed the Sabbath day and made it holy."
This verse begins with the word "for," which can also be translated "because." In other words, it seems God is grounding to the Israelites his command to observe the Sabbath in his creation pattern. Am I missing something? Grammatically, it seems to me God is effectively saying, "because" I myself rested on the 7th day after creation, you therefore are to rest too. Although this is a command in the Old Covenant, under which New Covenant Christians are no longer bound, the grounding in Creation (and the facts of Creation never change, unlike the binding and fulfillment of covenants) could be seen as making this commandment in particular binding on everyone, at all times, forever, even though it is an Old Covenant law. The fact of God resting on the 7th day will never change, and since this is his grounds for the commandment to observe the Sabbath in Exodus 20, it almost seems as if the Sabbath commandment should be binding on his people, including New Covenant Christians forever.
Question: In light of your conviction that the Law is no longer binding on New Covenant Believers, how should we make sense of Exodus 20:11 in particular?
I am asking specifically how to reconcile this verse with all the Scriptural data, and not a vague and general debate on Sabbath-keeping. Full disclosure, personally, all my life I believed the Sabbath did not apply to Christians because of all the data in the New Testament on how to view the Law. But I am so lost on how to reconcile my current theology together with a coherent theology from Exodus 20:11.

Who believes that the 10 commandments are no longer binding? Certainly very few believe that the laws against adultery and murder no longer apply. As with "honor your father and mother" this is a question of how the law is properly observed not whether it still applies.

@DanFefferman I'm one of them! I consider the Law to still be binding, for those in the old Mosaic Covenant. For Christians it's like the laws of another country - we're not in their jurisdiction so they're not binding on us, but they can still inform our thinking and actions, as they are an expression of the eternal will and morality of God. In my understanding, saying that the 6th and 7th commandments (murder/adultery) are binding on Christians is like saying that the laws of Brazil are binding on Japanese citizens. Christians instead are bound to the Law of Christ.

One might also consider that Genesis 2:3 (which properly should be the end of chapter 1) describes the 7th day of Creation: "And God blessed the seventh day and declared it holy, because it was the day when he rested from all his work of creation.". From the beginning the seventh day was created as something holy to God, not something that was created twenty five hundred years later as part of a specific covenant. That covenant with Israel simply defined how the Israelites should respect God's holy day.

@curiousdannii, just the type of person I was looking for! I still need your answer! I actually agree with you 100% thus far, that the Law is not binding for the reasons you listed, which is precisely why I am struggling in my question. In my original post, my question, "In light of your conviction that the Law is no longer binding on New Covenant Believers, how should we make sense of Exodus 20:11 in particular?" How do you make sense of Exodus 20:11's grounding of the imperative with an eternal fact of God - creation order - rather than a temporary fact about Israel?


This is a question particularly for those who believe, based on Biblical data in the New Testament, that the Sabbath is no longer binding for New Covenant Christians, since Jesus has fulfilled the Law and has become our rest.

I don't know what to do with your "Jesus ... has become our rest" phrase, so I don't know if I meet the criteria to answer or not; but otherwise, I do fall in the camp of those who contend that New Covenant Christians are not bound by any of the law, not even the Ten Commandments.
My hermeneutical approach simply recognizes that Israel is distinct from the church and that the church has different obligations than Israel did. It is pretty straight-forward. Exodus 20:11 indeed grounds the Sabbath observance within the Mosaic Covenant in the 6-day creation. However, there is nothing in the NT which suggests that this observance has now been imposed on the church at-large. Rather, just the opposite, as Paul stands against those who would impose the observance of special holidays or the Sabbath onto non-Jewish believers (Col. 2:16).

"Paul stands against those who would impose the observance of special holidays or the Sabbath onto non-Jewish believers (Col. 2:16)" — Rather, just the opposite. Paul is talking about non-Christians who would prevent the observance of holidays by Christians.  See my answer to exegesis - Keeping the Sabbath and Colossians 2:16.

Exodus 20:11 follows verse 1 which has God addressing the people God brought "out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of bondage." The laws that followed started with what has later become known as The Ten Commandments, and a whole raft of other laws. At the giving of these laws, Mount Sinai was smoking, there was terrible thunder, lightning, and the sound of trumpets. The people brought out of Egyptian slavery were terrified and stood far off. Yet they agreed to keep the laws God stated. They were unable to keep them, however, because God's law is perfect, and they were imperfect sinners. That law was designed to convince them of their total inability to keep God's laws. It was designed to prepare them to humbly accept that fact. That law was to be their tutor to lead them to the Son of God as the only means of salvation for repentant sinners. Those under the law were redeemed by Christ, and no longer under its rule/authority - Galatians 4:4.
That is why Christians cannot take Exodus 20:11 as applying to them. They have been led, in faith, to Jesus Christ, the Lord of the Sabbath. They have been liberated from bondage to futile attempts to keep God's perfect law. The law has served its purpose with them, personally. They know from painful experience that even with the best will in the world not to, they break God's law, and whoever breaks it at one point, breaks all of it (James 2:10). They have been convicted of their hopelessly sinful state by that law. But now, as Paul said to Christians, "Ye are not under the law but under grace" Romans 6:14. Also, that all who believe are justified from all things which they could not be justified from by the law of Moses (Acts 13:39 & John 1:17).
What has muddied otherwise clear waters, is the way some have attempted to divide the Old Covenant law into three parts - the ceremonial, the judicial, and the moral law of God. This is in order to enable them to "deal with" what is stated in Colossians 2:13-17:

"And you, being dead in your sins and the uncircumcision of your
flesh, hath he quickened together with him, having forgiven you all
trespasses; Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was
against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way,
nailing it to the cross... Let no man therefore judge you in
meat, or in drink, or in respect of an holyday, or of the new moon,
or of the sabbath: which are a shadow of things to come; but the body is of Christ." A.V. [Bold emphases mine]

Those who still wish a degree of legalism to add to the gospel of grace claim that only the ceremonial and judicial aspects of the law were removed at the cross. They claim that the moral aspect never was. What? Only two-thirds of the law was removed? That's not what the scripture says! This artificial categorising is what legs people down. This is what muddies the waters. It is the supposed 'moral law' that is the bit that truly stands against us!
Christians should know that they are spiritual Israel, not fleshly Israel; that they are represented by the free-woman Sarah and Jerusalem above, not the bond-woman Hagar and Mount Sinai. Galatians 4:21-31 starts by asking those Christians to still be under the law whether they hear the law (then gives the allegory of Sarah and Hagar). That alone should be enough for Christians to discover just how free in Christ they truly are. Not free to sin or to do what they like; but to enter into God's rest, resting from their own works, and if there ever was a work of self-righteousness it surely is in keeping a list of do's and don't with regard to one day in the week! The bar is now far higher than that - we observe seven days a week as unto the Lord of the Sabbath, Christ.
This means that my answer has no need of any reference to Creation. Not for Christians. Yes, for fleshly Israelites. But Christians are spiritual Israelites and are now already in God's spiritual sabbath-rest, all the time. We worship God and put him first seven days a week, not just one! Further, the Creation order for this material creation is one day going to be consumed by fire and even the heavens will disappear, to be replaced with a new heavens and a new earth, in which righteousness shall dwell. The old order will vanish. It is not set in stone for eternity, especially as the law is only for sinners. When all things will be made new, the new humanity will be liberated into the glorious freedom of the sons of God. Yet, already, we are released from what we could never keep, and live by faith in the Son of God. The Christian's rule of life is the law of Christ, not the law that no human is capable of keeping. It has served its purpose. We are free in Christ, even now.

Excellent answer. +1

Rubbish....read Romans...paul says even Abraham was saved by faith...thats the new covenant 2 thousand years before Christ. The law and covenants have not changed. In Revelation, we are still judged by the same standard...ie 10 commandments. Read Revelation 14.12...what are the qualities of the saints in this verse? Are they not those who keep the commandments (10 commandments) and have the testimony of Christ? (GOSPEL). Revelation was written 60 years after Christ in the AD 90's!

@adam Yes, Abraham was saved without any law-keeping or sabbatian observance on his part. Faith saves, not legalism. I have read Rev.14:12 as you urge. "The faith of Jesus" was trusting in the Father to keep his promises, not legalistic living, which he condemned the Pharisees for. Christians are to go to Jesus for life, which they refused to do, preferring their system of rules and law-keeping. Rev.14:12 does not even hint at The Ten Commandments; you are reading that into it; biazogesis.

@Anne...it was the pharasees who made the law a burden...not the people. Also, read Revelation 14.12 again...what is the FIRST quality of the saints? "Here are those who keep the commandments". The faith/testimony of Christ is the second. This means salvation hinges on both.fulfillment that you talk about is the fulfillment of the promise spoken to the serpent  that the seed of Eve would crush the serpernts head...that Christ would make atonement for wages of sin in Genesis 3. As I said before, how can we be judged at the judgement if there is no moral standard? The law is still Here.

@adam Those who are born again, who are "in Christ" and who have the Spirit of God dwelling in them have the righteous requirements of the Law fulfilled in them by walking in the Spirit and not in the flesh (Romans 8:4).  This fulfilling is in the passive tense.  The saints "keep the commandments" only in the sense that the indwelling Spirit does so within them.  That is why we cannot please God by walking in the flesh but only in the Spirit.  Kai is copulative so keeping the commandments and the faith of Jesus are not two separate items but joined together into one.


OP:  In light of your conviction that the Law is no longer binding on New Covenant Believers, how should we make sense of Exodus 20:11 in particular?

Does God still create or is He at rest?

And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made. Gen 2:2

For the Israelites, this would be remembered by their resting on the seventh day.  It is part of their Mosaic Law Covenant.

For in six days the LORD made heaven and earth, the sea, and all that in them is, and rested the seventh day: wherefore the LORD blessed the sabbath day, and hallowed it. Exo 20:11

What about the New Covenant?  What is the 7th day in the New Covenant?
For believers, the 7th day is the perpetual 8th day.  Bear with me.
We know God rested from all His work.  What did He do at sunset 7th day to the start of the 8th day?  For believers, He rose out from the dead.  This fulfilled His promise.

Let us therefore fear, lest, a promise being left us of entering into his rest, any of you should seem to come short of it. For unto us was the gospel preached, as well as unto them: but the word preached did not profit them, not being mixed with faith in them that heard it. For we which have believed do enter into rest, as he said, As I have sworn in my wrath, if they shall enter into my rest: although the works were finished from the foundation of the world. For he spake in a certain place of the seventh day on this wise, And God did rest the seventh day from all his works. And in this place again, If they shall enter into my rest. Heb 4:1-5

A promise made to enter God's rest, not to be repeated every 7th day, but on the perpetual 8th day, the today day.

Again, he limiteth a certain day, saying in David, To day, after so long a time; as it is said, To day if ye will hear his voice, harden not your hearts.  Heb 4:7

The word "limiteth" means "to mark out the boundaries or limits".  It means today today and tomorrow it means today and the next day is today, every day is the 8th day.
So, to answer the OP, we make sense of the 7th day of rest after God ended His work as a prophecy of the 8th day wherein believers rest perpetually in Christ from all our work to be made perfect in His sight.
EDIT TO ADD:
Barnabas circa 100AD makes mention of the eighth day in a similar manner.

Then we shall be able to sanctify it, having been first sanctified ourselves.1668 Further, He says to them, “Your new moons and your Sabbaths I cannot endure.”1669 Ye perceive how He speaks: Your present Sabbaths are not acceptable to Me, but that is which I have made, [namely this,] when, giving rest to all things, I shall make a beginning of the eighth day, that is, a beginning of another world. Wherefore, also, we keep the eighth day with joyfulness, the day also on which Jesus rose again from the dead.1670 And1671 when He had manifested Himself, He ascended into the heavens. Chapter XV

Augustine speaks of the eighth day in this manner.

And he himself preached, saying, "There cometh one mightier than I after me."2093  In like manner, therefore, the circumcision on the eighth day, which was given to the patriarchs, foretold our justification, to the putting away of carnal lusts through the resurrection of our Lord, which took place after the seventh day, which is the Sabbath-day, on the eighth, that is, the Lord’s day, Responses to Peter Chapter 37


The Law of Moses is a shadow of the Law of Christ. It shows us the rough outline and has numerous correspondences to the fullness that is found in Christ. Therefore we are taught by Christ to observe a spiritual sabbath, but not according to the regulations found in the Law of Moses.
If you break the Ten Commandments into pieces, there are fourteen imperative statements. The Sabbath commandment has three imperative statements:

Observe the Sabbath and keep it Holy
Work six days
Don't work on the seventh day

If you divide the Gospel of Matthew into fourteen pieces, taking two chapters for each piece, then each imperative statement matches one of those
pairs of chapters. Themes related to that imperative are addressed in the corresponding chapters. By this logic, the three imperatives for the Sabbath commandment match Matthew 9-14.
Thus, if you want teaching on how a Christian is to observe a spiritual sabbath as taught and modeled for us by Jesus, look to Matthew 9-14.
This concept is worked out in detail in my book, Plague, Precept, Prophet, Peace, which explores the Ten Commandments. The relevant chapter is also found on my website in this article:
Matthew and the Law of Christ

The law of Moses is not the 10 commandments. The law of Moses referred to the book of the law. The 10 commandments have always been The Law of the Lord

Yeah terrible answer. -1 from me.
